# Python selenium microsoft sign with certificate

Tags: python, selenium, office365

Iam using python with selenium on mac and I need to access sharepoint web side.(I tested it on chromedrive and edge both same problem)

The issue is with this pop up to select a certificate and have no idea how to click to enter.

When I use chrome (without selenium manually click) no pop up coming.

thank you for help[image: Select certificate]

Chrome and Edge is working when I dont use selenium and make it manualy no certificate is needed

Comment: Are you running i locally or on a server? If its the server you would need to install that cert, With Selenium you cannot click on the Pop-up

Comment: Its running on PC. When I use ont this pc standard chrome I dont need to to select certificate. When I use python and seleniun with chrome driver this window pop up and I need to select cert. how can I import cert to selenium?